# Artifacts on my explosion render

Tags: rendering, artifacts

i have  a problem , because when i render my project. On my scene appears rectangle.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.se. Please do some more troubleshooting. Have you Replaced the simulation with simple geometry (Cube) (does the rectangle still appear)? Have you tried to make the background transparent. Have you unhid Alt H all objects in the scene? Have you removed all other objects except for the simulation?

Comment: You could also use this: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ ...to share the file with us so we could help much faster.